# Implementing JNDI with Springboot and JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jndi, tomcat9

I try to configure JNDI in Tomcat. I tried it using 2 springboot applications.

- The first application is using springboot starter jdbc
- The second is using springboot starter jpa

On both applications controllers are the same:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/employees",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getEmployees() {
    System.out.println("inside  getEmployees() method ....");
    List<Employee> employeeList = repository.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I also configured jndi in my application properties:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB
```

In my repository class in the application that uses springboot starter jdbc:

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeRepository {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from EMPLOYEE", new EmployeeRowMapper());
    }
}
```

On the other I use JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, Long> {
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    List<EmployeeEntity> findAll();
}
```

So far so good. server.xml and context.xml are correctly configured in tomcat. For this test I am using MySQL v.5...
The application containing the springboot starter jdbc, i do access the database data using the get method. In the other application, the war is deployed but not started.

I have actually 3 issues:

1. I try using JNDI to handle a connection pool
2. Most of my developments are using JPA (i have many webservices for my application ...)
3. the last issue should be a new question: is there a way to use the Tomcat connexion pool to the database from an external application ? For example having a jar using the same connexion pool. For this point i didn't find any sample

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue doing the following:
I created a configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "fr.company.jndi.data.repository")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = null;

        Context ctx = null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And i also downgraded my spring boot version from version 3.0.0 to version 2.7.4-SNAPSHOT for example. I also added the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```